# How can i download the PDF file in spring mvc?

Tags: java, spring, pdf, model-view-controller

this is my file path

```
public final static String BOOKINGPDFFILE= "D:/Hotels/pdf/";
```

This below code is what  I have written to download pdf from the above resource folder

```
Pdf="column name in database  i used for storing in database"

@RequestMapping(value = "/getpdf/{pdf}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public  void getPdf(@PathVariable("pdf") String fileName, HttpServletResponse response,HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {


   try {
        File file = new File(FileConstant.BOOKINGPDFFILE + fileName+ ".pdf");


        Files.copy(file.toPath(),response.getOutputStream());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Contract Not Found");
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You may try something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(method = { RequestMethod.GET }, value = { "/downloadPdf" })
    public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> downloadPdf()
    {
        try
        {
            File file = new File(BOOKINGPDFFILE);
            HttpHeaders respHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
            MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf");
            respHeaders.setContentType(mediaType);
            respHeaders.setContentLength(file.length());
            respHeaders.setContentDispositionFormData("attachment", file.getName());
            InputStreamResource isr = new InputStreamResource(new FileInputStream(file));
            return new ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource>(isr, respHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            String message = "Errore nel download del file "+idForm+".csv; "+e.getMessage();
            logger.error(message, e);
            return new ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
```

And in your web page you can write the link in this way:

```
<a href="/yourWebAppCtx/yourControllerRoot/downloadPdf" target="_blank"> download PDF </a>
```

Comment: Where is `ResponseEntity` imported from?

Answer (score 4):

Here is the way, hope it help.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getpdf/{pdf}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public  void getPdf(@PathVariable("pdf") String fileName, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

    try {
        File file = new File(FileConstant.BOOKINGPDFFILE + fileName+ ".pdf");

        if (file.exists()) {
            // here I use Commons IO API to copy this file to the response output stream, I don't know which API you use.
            FileUtils.copyFile(file, response.getOutputStream());

            // here we define the content of this file to tell the browser how to handle it
            response.setContentType("application/pdf");
            response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName + ".pdf");
            response.flushBuffer();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Contract Not Found");
        }
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        System.out.println("Contract Not Found");
        System.out.println(exception.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: i am also using Commons IO but  in this portion  I am getting error FileUtils.copyFile(file, response.getOutputStream());

Comment: If you could leave more detail about the error and your Spring MVC configuration I could help you.

Comment: The error is basically 404 not found .when i click the download button it redirects into new tab and displays "404 not found." do i need to add <mvc:resources mapping="/getpdf/**" location="D:/Hotels/pdf/" /> this portion i am using 4.0.1 spring framework ..itext for pdf generation

Comment: Look, you are misunderstanding the resource tag usage because this is configured to declare public resources to the WEB like images, static html, etc. Probably you are using itext to generate your PDF and doing this in your OS temp directory. If this is not the case, then I recommend you to use this folder for this kind of work. Then once you have the file ready to download you simply use this code to indicate where is your file:
    `File file = new File(FileUtils.getTempDirectoryPath() + "/" +fileName+ ".pdf");`. The magic is done with the `response.flushBuffer();` instruction.

Comment: What you are doing with the instruction that I've provided is: 1. copy my file to the buffer that will be written in the client (the browser in this case). 2. tell the client what will be the content and the name of the file to be handle. 3. commit this file to the client.

Comment: here is my anchor tag which redirects to new browser but display 404 not found <a href="${SITE_URL}/booking/getPdf/${booking.pdf}" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary"  >
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash">Confirmation</span>
                  </a>

Comment: OK, let me finish my working day, build a proof of concept and upload it to github.

Comment: thank you very much I really appreciate your help .It is really kind of you to help beginner like me

Comment: Building my POC I realized that your URL is not according to the Controller URL, you have to change 'P' for 'p' in your anchor. Check this out and inform me back if you have another problem.

Comment: I finished my POC and I'm getting my PDF with Chrome opening its pdf viewer. So I think that your problem is a case sensitive issue.

Comment: No problem, I like to share experiences so I do it with pleasure.

Comment: Hi @Gabriel, I'm using the same code to download a pdf file. But what I have noticed is - it downloads a blank file. Suppose if there are 5 pages in the file to be downloaded, the downloaded version has those 5 pages but all are blank.

Comment: And when I use the produces app/pdf property in my controller class the pdf file gets downloaded correctly. But i'm unable to throw exception in that case as it returns [object object].

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an implementation of AbstractPdfView to achieve this.. You can refer this link  https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-export-data-to-pdf-file-via-abstractpdfview/

Comment: ok I am going through it what if i want to open the file in browser it self in next tab

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Detailed answer for your question.
let me start with the server side code:

Below class is used to create pdf with some random content and return the equivalent byte array outputstream.

```
public class pdfgen extends AbstractPdfView{

 private static ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

public ByteArrayOutputStream showHelp() throws Exception {
    Document document = new Document();
   // System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document,byteArrayOutputStream);
    document.open();
    document.add(new Paragraph("table"));
    document.add(new Paragraph(new Date().toString()));
    PdfPTable table=new PdfPTable(2);

    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell (new Paragraph ("table"));

    cell.setColspan (2);
    cell.setHorizontalAlignment (Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    cell.setPadding (10.0f);
    //cell.setBackgroundColor (new BaseColor (140, 221, 8));                                  

    table.addCell(cell);                                    
    ArrayList<String[]> row=new ArrayList<String[]>();
    String[] data=new String[2];
    data[0]="1";
    data[1]="2";
    String[] data1=new String[2];
    data1[0]="3";
    data1[1]="4";
    row.add(data);
    row.add(data1);

    for(int i=0;i<row.size();i++) {
      String[] cols=row.get(i);
      for(int j=0;j<cols.length;j++){
        table.addCell(cols[j]);
      }
    }

    document.add(table);
    document.close();

    return byteArrayOutputStream;   
}
```

}

Then comes the controller code : here the bytearrayoutputstream is converted to bytearray and sent to the client side using the response-entity with appropriate headers.

```
@RequestMapping(path="/home")
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> render(HttpServletRequest request , HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException
{
  pdfgen pg=new pdfgen();
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment:filename=report.pdf");
    byte[] contents = null;
    try {
        contents = pg.showHelp().toByteArray();
    } 
  catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  //These 3 lines are used to write the byte array to pdf file
  /*FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/Users/naveen-pt2724/desktop/nama.pdf");
  fos.write(contents);
  fos.close();*/
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"));
//Here you have to set the actual filename of your pdf
    String filename = "output.pdf";
    headers.setContentDispositionFormData(filename, filename);
    headers.setCacheControl("must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    ResponseEntity<byte[]> respons = new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(contents, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    return respons;
}
```

> The header should be set to "application/pdf"

Then comes the client side code :
Where you can make ajax request to server to open the pdf file in new tab of the browser

```
 $.ajax({
            url:'/PDFgen/home',
            method:'POST',
            cache:false,
             xhrFields: {
                    responseType: 'blob'
                  },
              success: function(data) {
                  //alert(data);
                let blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/pdf'}); //mime type is important here
                let link = document.createElement('a'); //create hidden a tag element
                let objectURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob); //obtain the url for the pdf file
                link.href = objectURL; // setting the href property for a tag
                link.target = '_blank'; //opens the pdf file in  new tab
                link.download = "fileName.pdf"; //makes the pdf file download
                (document.body || document.documentElement).appendChild(link); //to work in firefox
                link.click(); //imitating the click event for opening in new tab
              },
            error:function(xhr,stats,error){
                 alert(error);
            }  
        });
```

Comment: OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream(); is never used...

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the code, kindly upvote if it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/download")
public class FileDownloadController 
{
    @RequestMapping("/pdf/{fileName}")
    public void downloadPDFResource( HttpServletRequest request, 
                                     HttpServletResponse response, 
                                     @PathVariable("fileName") String fileName) 
    {
        //If user is not authorized - he should be thrown out from here itself
         
        //Authorized user will download the file
        String dataDirectory = request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/downloads/pdf/");
        Path file = Paths.get(dataDirectory, fileName);
        if (Files.exists(file)) 
        {
            response.setContentType("application/pdf");
            response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+fileName);
            try
            {
                Files.copy(file, response.getOutputStream());
                response.getOutputStream().flush();
            } 
            catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```